# initramfs fails to find root filesystem on recently updated system

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

On a recent installation of Ubuntu 18.04, the system has installed fine. However attempting to upgrade the systems kernel from kernel image 4.15.0-29-generic to 4.15.0-43-generic the kernel would panic due to no found root filesystem.

```
[   0.327121] md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect
[   0.327823] md: If you don't use raid, use raid=noautodetect
[   0.328622] md: Autotecting RAID arrays.
[   0.629322] md: autorun ...
[   0.330013] md: ... autorun DONE.
[   0.330722] VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID=<UUID>" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[   0.331434] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[   0.332162] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[   0.332878] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tained 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu
[   0.333599] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./X99 Extreme4, BIOS P2.00 06/01/2015
<KERNEL CALL TRACE>
```

As you can see when attempting to load the filesystem from within the current initramfs (4.15.0-43-generic) no disks are detected. Switching back to the previous initramfs (4.15.0-29-generic) still allowed the root filesystem to be detected and loaded.

At a later point (several updates) even the 4.15.0-29-generic initramfs failed to find the root filesystem.

As of right now I have checked all disks to SMART, flashed the motherboard with an updated UEFI firmware, and performed multiple fscks against the filesystem. At this point the GPT layout looks fine, there are no filesystem errors, and SMART has come back with no disk faults or errors.

The only way I have found to continue booting the system is to pull the initramfs modules from the Ubuntu 18.04 Live CD and rebuilt the original initramfs for 4.15.0-29-generic. This process has at least been met with limited success in that I can once again boot the system albeit without any extra modules such as the nvidia display drivers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT

#> blkid

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="9238-307A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="3a8561c9-9af9-4143-a82c-7af3ecd3284c"
/dev/sda2: UUID="94ddd972-a4d8-4317-8a0a-5a4abfdb9d06" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4a29cc34-5be1-4436-b842-fd203f3a522c"
/dev/sda3: UUID="23ec719e-030a-4ee1-9814-067365b10cb5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="27d64a6a-a723-41d0-8b68-2b9d0aec2833"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="26dc83b3-84db-462f-a2de-37399066036d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d367e4df-01"
```

#> cat /etc/fstab

```
UUID=94ddd972-a4d8-4317-8a0a-5a4abfdb9d06 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=23ec719e-030a-4ee1-9814-067365b10cb5 /home           ext4    default 0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=26dc83b3-84db-462f-a2de-37399066036d   <REDACTED>/26dc83b3-84db-462f-a2de-37399066036d ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 2
UUID=9238-307A  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

#> ls -la /boot

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Jan 16 09:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Dec 22 03:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1537161 Jul 17  2018 abi-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1538114 Nov 15 14:01 abi-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   216807 Jul 17  2018 config-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217018 Nov 15 14:01 config-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217018 Dec  6 08:52 config-4.15.0-43-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Jan 16 20:56 grub
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jan 15 21:00 grub.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54526834 Jan 15 22:03 initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 65974838 Jan 15 21:30 initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54526834 Jan 16 09:19 initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic.working
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 65987219 Jan 15 09:20 initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 65987219 Jan 15 21:30 initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 66556554 Jan 16 09:27 initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 65990605 Jan 15 21:30 initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55494929 Jan 16 09:21 initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic.working
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Jul 17  2018 retpoline-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Nov 15 14:01 retpoline-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4040379 Jul 17  2018 System.map-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4048025 Nov 15 14:01 System.map-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4048162 Dec  6 08:52 System.map-4.15.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8257272 Jul 24 23:33 vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8277752 Nov 15 14:04 vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8281848 Dec  6 08:56 vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8281848 Jan 16 09:21 vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic.working
```

Comment: Have you tried the `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-29-generic`?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I have tried this for all versions of the initramfs with no effect. It looks as if there is a module missing that fails to allow the kernel to find the hard drives. However when comparing the modules from the hacked together 4.15.0-29-generic and 4.15.0-43-generic there does not appear to be a different.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /boot`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Updated question to include relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. When you say "attempting to upgrade the systems kernel", are you upgrading JUST the kernel, and if so, where are you getting the kernel(s) from? Do all of -29, -42, and -43 boot with the same error? Can you successfully boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Also, what kernel is your Ubuntu Live 18.04 DVD booting from?

Comment: @heynnema Yes I have attempted upgrade from -29, -42, and -43 all with the same results. As for booting from a Ubuntu Live 18.04 DVD, it will boot successfully and reinstall successfully. It is after a perform a generalized upgrade or even a kernel specific upgrade that the inability to boot occurs. The Ubuntu 18.04 image I have uses a 4.15.00-29-generic kernel and initramfs image. It was this image I used to restore/repair my local 4.15.00-29-generic initramfs image and boot to the local machine.

Comment: As I recall, -29 through at least -36, and maybe further, the kernels had some major problems... I don't recall exactly what... causing me to do a late 18.10 upgrade, and that fixed the problem. Are you willing to try 18.10?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88521/discussion-between-blackninja543-and-heynnema).